# How to install windows 10 in Virtual machine without logging into any account?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm installing windows 10 from iso into virtual machine in virtual box. Through the installation windows wants to login into account. Is there any easy way how to proceed without login? Like disabling connection in virtual box or something like that?

Comment: "login into account" - What account?  Are you asking how to create a local account instead of an account linked to a Microsoft Account?  If that is the case you should [edit] your question to clarify it.

Comment: Adding a screenshot of the step where you got stuck will help. Various versions of Windows 10 differ quite a bit when it comes to this.

Comment: While installing Windows 10, use the keyboard shortcut to open a Command Prompt, and run `OOBE\BYPASSNRO`

Comment: Yes, I mean installation process, thank you I will try it @Ramhound

Comment: I'm stuck at log in into microsoft account which I don't want to. @gronostaj

Comment: @Dalton I understand this, but I'm not able to help you currently. As I already said Microsoft has changed this a number of times over multiple versions of Windows 10. I can't provide detailed instructions without seeing what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, see the comments by @Ramhound.

But it sounds like you are asking how to avoid signing into a Microsoft account. If this is the case, disabling the network passthrough to the VM and following the options in the Windows 10 installer for offline install will allow you to create a local Windows account without signing into a Microsoft account.

Comment: Yeah maybe I could have phrased it better. I mean the installation process. So disabling internet access in virtual machine, that could do it. Thank you.

Comment: @Dalton - You should [edit] your question now that you understand you should rephrase your question.

Comment: @Garrett - SImply not being connected to the internet has not avoided a Microsoft account since 21H2 was released on all editions (perhaps except Education and Enterprise).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for a Virtual Machine or a physical machine to install Windows 10 without an account. To do that you must complete the installation without a network connection. Since you are using a VM, you can easily just disable the virtual network until the installation completes and then activate it.

In VirtualBox, just select the machine you created before installing Windows. Open its *Settings* dialog box (not *Properties* - I used to confuse the two!) then you will see a list of components, one of the is *Network*. Select it.
Then you will see tabs for *Adapter 1* to *Adapter 4*. Make sure that in each tab, the *Enable Network Adapter* box is unchecked. By default only *Adapter 1* will be checked. Then install Windows 10 into the VM.

Alternatively, since the VM uses a bridged network, you can achieve the same end-result by disconnecting the host from the network, assuming you don't need it for anything during the VM installation.